# Как заполнить UTextureRenderTarget2D данными из другой текстуры?

Tags: unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine, unreal-engine-5

Каким образом можно задать или заполнить UTextureRenderTarget2D данными из UTexture2D?

Есть UTexture2D такого же размера.
Есть UTextureRenderTarget2D который нужно заполнить данными из UTexture2D.

```
UTexture2D * text;
UTextureRenderTarget2D * renderTarget;

renderTarget->UpdateTexture2D(text); // ?
```